# How to conditionally get a row from a pandas dataframe, if the cell content is a set and I want to see if a value is in it?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe called `DF` and a list of strings. One of the columns (`ALPHABET`) in `DF` contains values like `{'A'}` or `{'A', 'E'}` or similar set of alphabet. 
`strings_list = ['A', 'B', 'Z']`
I want to get rows from the dataframe where the set (value in the cell) contains `'A'` or `'B'` or `'Z'`.

I tried the following, but it did not work, I searched in stack, lots of question about `loc` but could not find this question.

`DF.loc[('A' in DF.ALPHABET) | ('B' in DF.ALPHABET) | ('Z' in DF.ALPHABET)]`

Is there any way other than looping through the dataframe?

Comment: [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: You can apply a filtering function to each element, and use it as a filtering condition. Not sure if that's what you mean by looping: `DF[DF.ALPHABET.apply(lambda x: bool(x.intersection({'A', 'B', 'C'})))]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) to check if any strings in `strings_list` is in set from `ALPHABET` column.

```
DF[DF['ALPHABET'].apply(lambda set: any(s in set for s in strings_list))]
```